# Capture values from JDBC requests and use for next query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to use Jmeter with about 10 queries per thread.  All I want each thread to do is Insert into a `player` table using mysql auto increment.  Then I want to use mysql

```
SELECT last_insert_id();
```

to grab the auto inc value and use it for the next query which is inserted into a `player_game` table.
How do I store the value returned and how do I call it in the next query?
I tried to save it in the variable name but can't seem to get it to insert correctly on the next query.

I then tried to call it using both `${player1id}` and `player1id` but couldn't get it to work.

Is there a better way to go about this?
Or how can I store that value for the next JDBC request?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Both the queries

```
Insert into player...
Insert into player_game...
```

have auto increment on player_id and player_game_id
I then need to insert into a third table player_game_round and I need to insert the values from both player_id and player_game_id as such:

```
INSERT INTO player_game_round (round, player_score, player_id, player_game_id)....
```

Comment: Look at this tutorial, it has what you want. http://90kts.com/2010/01/05/dynamic-data-from-jmeter-jdbc-requests/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly do

```
INSERT into player_game(player_id, game_id) values(last_insert_id(), 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for this query, but after that I do another into another table for example:

    Insert into player  -- player_id auto inc
    Insert into player_game  -- player_game_id auto inc
    Insert into player_game_round --player_game_round_id auto inc.

In the player_game_round I need the auto inc from player_id (which was 2 inserts before not just the last)